# Тест, экспортированный с Selenium не воспроизводится на Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, selenium

При воспроизведении теста, экспортированного из `Selenium` производится такая ошибка:

> ERROR: test_fdefd (**main**.Fdefd)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tests\fdefd.py", line 12, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmpeywhqv If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

> Ran 1 test in 93.277s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)

### Код программы:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Fdefd(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://bugscatcher.net/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_fdefd(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://automated-testing.info/t/selenium-podbiraem-lokatory/2269")
        driver.find_element_by_id("site-logo").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Тесты лучше не через Selenium IDE делать, а сразу руками писать. И в начале как раз придется разобраться, как же запускать браузер -- на этом-то месте ошибка и вылетает. Погуглите примеры кода по запросу Python+Selenium+Firefox. А еще лучше пишите на Ruby+Capybara ,.)

Comment: Попробуйте обновить selenium `pip install -U selenium`

Answer (score 1):

Код который генерирует Selenium IDE, надо править, но вы сможете это не раньше чем поймете что и где в коде происходит.

Не буду гадать что вы пытались проверить своим тестом, но например найти в яндексе слово *"Selenium"* , а потом проверить что в результатах есть их сайт можно следующим способом. (Python 3.x). Если нужны будут пояснения по коду, можете обращаться.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class testClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://www.yandex.ru")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def test_log_in(self):
        element_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="text"]')
        element_input.send_keys('Selenium')
        element_button_find = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="search2__button"]/button')
        element_button_find.click()
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Selenium - Web Browser Automation')
        except Exception as err:
            print('Some error:', err)

    def tearDown(self):
        print("Close browser")
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```